# Opposite actions combined in one split button

Tags: buttons, interface, actions

For the interface I'm working on, users can mark certain rows as "Verified", but they also have the option of marking them "Unverified". To do this, they select several rows by clicking on checkboxes and click on a button called, "Verify".

Should I include a separate button for "Unverify", like so:
[image: Exhibit A]

Or should I instead use a split button and include "Unverify" as a sub-action of verify, like so:
[image: Exhibit B]

A is clearer and I don't hide any action, but the objective is to get users to verify rows. I don't want users to accidentally be unverifying rows.

B hides one of the two actions and might be a problem for discovery, but is more space efficient and promotes the objective of verifying a row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thinking out loud) I think separate buttons are a must. Regarding the location of the buttons, I think it depends upon whether or not there's any instructional text. Then again, even if instructional text is included, proximity of the buttons with the rows they're addressing could prove to be an issue.

Answer: It's difficult to specify completely without knowing the full context of the experience. Based on what I'm seeing, you could also limit the interface to one button that only indicates which elements are verified. With that approach, however, error mitigation goals can't be accomplished.

I'm still convinced that separate buttons are a must. They should, however, be separated to help avoid people clicking the wrong button. I'll have to stop there with my response though, for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: Thanks, Darren! I see what you're saying, and I agree with your reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 6):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSz29s.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I might suggest putting the "Unverify" action into the context of each row, so that it's clearer that "Verify" is the primary action, and also to avoid accidental Unverifications.

Comment: Need to perform select checkbox and then click on 'Unverify' button? or if i click on 'Unverify' without select checkbox, what is the use of checkbox here?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Tim! The rows have individual actions already, the "unverify" button I'm looking to add is for bulk actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's confusing for user to separate it, because you need to put extra effort to make it's clear for the user that current state is just one of two possible states and explain how to switch to another state. I would rather use a toggle button.

I found [#9 in this example](https://www.webydo.com/blog/web-design/freebies/22-free-toggle-switch-button-psd-designs/) maybe suitable for the task.